# Jquery/Jquery Mobile - is there an event that fires before mobileinit

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm sitting on a plugin which needs to initate some things before the Jquery Mobile `mobileinit` event fires (overriding some JQM functionalities)

I don't really want to split up my plugin into two separate files, having to place one before Jquery-mobile.js. So I'm looking for events preceding `mobileinit`

I'm currently trying with `DOMContentLoaded`, but this is not really working.

My question:
Are there any events that precede `mobileinit`? Can I fire this event from a .js file sitting AFTER jquery mobile.js?

Thanks for input!

**EDIT:**
I'm trying in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uyecey/5/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, mobileinit is the first event fired. see line number 6632 of jquery mobile RC1.
You can fire your own event from some js file before jquery mobile. and do stuff there.
But you cant fire this event from a .js file sitting AFTER jquery mobile.js.

Comment: I was afraid so... Thanks for clearing this up. Since I need JQM to mobileinit for my widget to work I figured I can only hack into JQM or place another separate .js file before JQM. Both not optimal.